# Wordpress posts showing in SQL database but not in My wp-admin dashboard

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I transfered my site and I have a problem:

I cannot see any Worpdress posts that I had, and when I go inside my phpMyAdmin they are there, in wp-posts table.

All of the URLs are correct and the rest of the URL paths and everything is fine.

Does anyone have an idea how to restore that posts from SQL?

Comment: check $table_prefix = 'wp_'; in wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

It would have probably been better to use the wordpress export functionality.

If you moved this from multi-site, then the table names may be different. For example wp_posts may have been wp_2_posts.

You may want to check the wordpress config files to see what it expects for the table names.